# SAS HANA Date from data step in PRO

Tags: sas, hana, proc-sql

A little new to SAS here.  I am using the following data step to get the first and last day of the month.

```
    Data _NULL_;
    begindt=IntNX("Month", Date(), 0) ;
    enddt=IntNX("Month", Date(),0,'E');
    PUT begindt=E8601DA. enddt=E8601DA.;
    Run;
```

The data step gets the results of begindt=2021-09-01 and enddt=2021-09-30.

However, I am having trouble converting the value to a date format to use in a where claus in a PROC SQL statement later in the program.  The commented out code works, but I can't get the date from data step in the correct format for the PROC SQL statement to work.

```
    /*  AND "DETAILAR"."CLEAR_DOC_POSTING_DATE" = '2021-09-01' */
    AND "DETAILAR"."CLEAR_DOC_POSTING_DATE" = begindt
```

Comment: Is the SQL snippet you showed being used in SAS code? Or is it part of some SQL code that is being passed to a foreign database using FROM CONNECTION TO syntax in SAS?

Comment: Yes, it is part of SQL code that is getting passed to a HANA database.

Answer (score 0):

SAS has date and time literals that make dealing with dates and times easy. SAS dates are the number of days since Jan 1 1960, and SAS datetimes are the number of seconds since Jan 1 1960. SAS automatically converts date literals to these times for you. Some examples of date and datetime literals:

```
'04SEP2021'd
'04SEP2021:00:00'dt
```

You don't have to use these all the time*, but they make debugging way easier. In your case, you simply need to feed a date literal into `proc sql`. If you're connecting to SAP HANA through SAS, the SAS/ACCESS engine to SAP will handle the conversion for you.

```
data _null_
    begindt = intnx('month', today(), 0, 'B');
    enddt   = intnx('month', today(), 0, 'E');

    call symputx('begindt', put(begindt, date9.) );
    call symputx('enddt', put(enddt, date9.) );
run;
```

Or, equivalently:

```
%let begindt = %sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(today()), 0, B), date9.);
%let enddt   = %sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(today()), 0, E), date9.);
```

Now you have two macro variables that you can not only easily read, but SAS will convert them for you. You can view them below:

```
%put &begindt;
%put &enddt;
```

Simply add them as date literals to your `where` clause in `proc sql` and let SAS do the rest.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select *
        from have 
        where CLEAR_DOC_POSTING_DATE BETWEEN "&begindt"d AND "&enddate"d
    ;
quit;
```

There are other literals too, like time literals, hex literals and name literals for variables with spaces in them.

```
 '10:00't - Time Literal
 '32'x - Hex literal
 'this is a var'n - Name literal
```

*proc timeseries, proc timedata, and proc tsmodel require date/datetime literals for the `start` and `end` options. But those are the only ones I know of.

Comment: Thank you!  This code worked!  I just couldn't get my arguments in order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate code like `'2021-09-01'` then why not create a macro variable with that string in it?

In your data _null_ step use:

```
call symputx('begindt',quote(put(intnx('month',date(),0),yymmdd10.),"'"));
```

Working from the inside out that statement will:

- calculate today's date
- convert to the start of the month
- convert to a 10 character string representing that date
- add single quotes around the string
- store the value into a macro variable named `begindt`

Now you reference the macro variable to generate the code you want

```
and "DETAILAR"."CLEAR_DOC_POSTING_DATE" = &begindt.
```

Which will generate the code:

```
and "DETAILAR"."CLEAR_DOC_POSTING_DATE" = '2021-09-01'
```

Comment: Thank you!  Thank you!  This code works perfectly.